# My Nexus 6P just entered bootloop mode

Tags: boot-loop, huawei, nexus-6p

While doing absolutely nothing, my phone, Huawei Nexus 6P entered a boot-loop mode (it's not going further than showing "Google" text). The only thing I can do is to enter secret menu, but when selecting "Recovery mode", nothing happens. OEM is locked, fastboot flashing unlock is not working because of this. Now I am trying to figure out what happened and I got nothing yet. Does this happened to some of you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happened to me you need to call android support and tell them your serial code and then you work with them from there if that does not work send it off to where it came from p.s make sure they are legit if you give them your serial code

Comment: Thank you for your response! In a way or another, the phone entered boot-loop while sending a photo through Whatsapp :)) Hopefully is not because of their app, because it's really weird. Anyway, this boot-loop thing is crazy, don't know if it is from the last update for Nexus 6P.